# Не работает кнопка открывающая текст

Tags: javascript

Есть код, по которому должна появляться кнопка которая будет показывать больший текст, и скрывать его в случае необходимости, (нужно на чистом JS), текст лаже не скрывается в начале, но кнопка появляется (хотя изначальна скрыта)

```
let originalText = document.getElementById("textmama").innerHTML
let text = document.getElementById("textmama");
let btn =  document.getElementById("rndBUT1");
function initData() {
    if (text.innerHTML.length > 100) {
        btn.style.display = "inline";
        text = text.innerHTML.substring(0,100) + " ...";
        btn.onclick = readmore ();
    }
}

function hidemore() {
    document.getElementById("textmama").innerHTML = originalText.substring(0,100) + " ..."
    let btn = document.getElementById("rndBUT1")
    btn.onclick = readmore()
}   
        
function readmore () {
    document.getElementById("textmama").innerHTML = originalText;
    let btn = document.getElementById("rndBUT1");
    btn.onclick = hidemore() ;
    
}

initData();
```

HTML файл

```
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="textmama">
    </p> Задача организации, в особенности же дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности создаёт предпосылки качественно новых шагов для направлений прогрессивного развития. Разнообразный и богатый опыт новая модель организационной деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации всесторонне сбалансированных нововведений. Равным образом выбранный нами инновационный путь позволяет оценить значение направлений прогрессивного развития. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности в значительной степени обуславливает создание экономической целесообразности принимаемых 
    </div>
    
    <button name="Читать далее:" style="display: none;" id=rndBUT1>  </button>
</p>
 <p>
  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут у вас, кажется, опечатка:

```js
text = text.innerHTML.substring(0,100) + " ...";
```

Наверное, имелось в виду:

```js
text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0,100) + " ...";
```

И как ниже подсказывают, обработчиками событий нужно назначать не результаты вызовов функций, а сами функции:

```
btn.onclick = readmore;

btn.onclick = hidemore;
```

Comment: опечатка и все? `btn.onclick = hidemore() ;` это что сделает?